# Создание динамической библиотеки (.so) с ресурсами

Tags: dll, c++, linux

Я хочу сделать `.so`, которая будет выводить *png*-изображения на экран. В библиотеке *gtk+* я нашёл функцию `gtk_image_new_from_file`.

Но я хочу загружать картинки не из файла, а из ресурсов библиотеки.

Меня интересует вопрос - возможно ли в *shared object* внести ресурсные файлы (*png*, *bmp*-изображения) так же, как это можно делать с *dll* под *ms/windows*?

Comment: внести можно - создайте себе свою секцию в elf файле. [рассказ о том, как сделать доп.секцию](http://web.archive.org/web/20130208160604/http://web.archive.org/web/20081120013357/http://qnx.org.ru/article9.html). Вот к [примеру](http://www.compholio.com/elfres/) человек пытается эмулировать поведение проводика винды в убунте.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. но только 1я ссылка не перенаправляется никуда.

Comment: там странная ссылка

    http://web.archive.org/web/20130208160604/http://web.archive.org/web/20081120013357/http://qnx.org.ru/article9.html

Answer (score 2):

вольный (и, вероятно, не очень верный) перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4864879/4827341) (исходный текст — в виде комментариев):

---

при помощи программы `convert` из [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) (одноимённый пакет входит в репозитории всех популярных дистрибутивов операционной системы *gnu/linux*):

```
$ convert file.png data.h
```

вы получите что-то вроде:

```
/*
  data.h (PNM).
*/
static unsigned char
  MagickImage[] =
  {
    0x50, 0x36, 0x0A, 0x23, 0x43, 0x72, 0x65, 0x61, 0x74, 0x65, 0x64, 0x20, 
    0x77, 0x69, 0x74, 0x68, 0x20, 0x47, 0x49, 0x4D, 0x50, 0x0A, 0x32, 0x37, 
    0x37, 0x20, 0x31, 0x36, 0x32, 0x0A, 0x32, 0x35, 0x35, 0x0A, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 

....
```

для совместимости с остальным кодом можно использовать либо `fmeopen()` и получить «обычный» объект `FILE *`, либо, альтернативно, воспользоваться `std::stringstream` для создания `iostream`. `std::stringstream` не очень хорош для этого, и вы, конечно, можете использовать указатель в любом месте, где можно использовать *iterator*.

если вы пользуетесь *automake*-ом, не забудьте установить соответствующий [BUILT_SOURCES](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/Built-Sources-Example.html).

---

положительные моменты такого подхода:

1. вы получаете текстовый файл, с которым сможет работать система контроля версий, его можно будет «патчить».
2. это переносимо и чётко определено на каждой платформе.