# Binary linking, чем можно заменить опции ld --relocatable -b в Visual Studio?

Tags: c, gcc

GNU linker (**ld**) позволяет создать объектный файл с **.data** секцией с содержимым любого файла. Для этого есть опции `-r (--relocatable)` и `-b (--format=binary)`

```
ld -r -b binary -o example.o example.jpg

# objdump -t example.o

SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 l    d  .data  00000000 .data
00004fc0 g       .data  00000000 _binary_example_jpg_end
00004fc0 g       *ABS*  00000000 _binary_example_jpg_size
00000000 g       .data  00000000 _binary_example_jpg_start
```

К этим данным можно обращаться в коде:

```
extern const unsigned char _binary_example_jpg_start[];
extern const unsigned char _binary_example_jpg_end[];
size_t len = _binary_example_jpg_end - _binary_example_jpg_start;
```

Как это можно портировать на Visual Studio? Язык Си.

Comment: А почему именно VS? mingw не подойдет? Мне кажется, у тамошнего ld точно должны быть соответствующие опции.

Comment: [такой вариант](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/441994/178576) сохранения изображений — вполне переносим.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вопрос состоит в том, как скомпилировать чужой код в VS, желательно меняя код по-минимуму.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Линковка ресурсов не описана в стандарте, и является системно-зависимой фичей. Visual Studio поддерживает стандартные для Windows ресурсы, точно так же как gcc скорее всего поддерживает стандартные ресурсы для своих целевых платформ.

Стандартом для Visual Studio является работа с [ресурсным файлом](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3sk7e6b.aspx) (*.rc), который автоматически подлинковывается к исполнимому файлу. Есть набор Windows-специфических функций для работы с такими файлами.

Если вы хотите создать переносимое приложение, возможно, вам придётся делать по-разному для разных платформ. Это означает достаточно сильную переделку кода. Но что ж делать, если код написан непереносимым образом?

Answer (score 1):

Совместно с ментейнером проекта решили использовать [char массивы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/441994/177333) (как и предложил  alexander barakin), как наиболее переносимый вариант.